# Исключение System.InvalidOperationException при задании значении свойству Label.Text

Tags: c#

Используется следующий код для формирования значения на Label.

```
///Метод является членом класса LabelReg, LabelReg отнаследован от Label
protected void reg_OnResultRead(Reg sender, ModBusCommon.Error result, object data)
{
    ///Получили новые данные
    double value = Convert.ToDouble(data) * Factor;

    ///Формируется текст для вывода
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    ///Если заданы размерности параметра, формируем текст по формату
    if (Units.Length > 0)
    {
        sb.Append(DisplayFormat.Replace("<VALUE>", value.ToString(Format)));
        sb.Replace("<UNITS>", Units);
    }
    else
        sb.Append(value.ToString(Format));

    Action d = () =>
    {
        ///Собственно здесь происходит исключение
        this.Text = sb.ToString();

        this.Enabled = (result == ModBusCommon.Error.OK);
    };

    if (this.InvokeRequired)
        this.Invoke(d);
    else
        d();
}
```

Периодически, при присваивании свойству Text вылетает исключение **System.InvalidOperationException**

**Коллекция была изменена после создания экземпляра перечислителя.**

> в System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary.NodeEnumerator.MoveNext()
>
> в System.Windows.Forms.Layout.DefaultLayout.ApplyCachedBounds(IArrangedElement
>   container)
>
> в System.Windows.Forms.Layout.DefaultLayout.xLayout(IArrangedElement
>   container, Boolean measureOnly, Size& preferredSize)
>
> в System.Windows.Forms.Layout.DefaultLayout.LayoutCore(IArrangedElement
>   container, LayoutEventArgs args)
>
> в System.Windows.Forms.Layout.LayoutEngine.Layout(Object container,
>   LayoutEventArgs layoutEventArgs)
>
> в System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs levent)
>
> в System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs
>   levent)
>
> в System.Windows.Forms.Control.PerformLayout(LayoutEventArgs args)
>
> в System.Windows.Forms.Control.PerformLayout()
>
> в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ResumeLayout(Boolean performLayout)
>
> в System.Windows.Forms.Layout.LayoutTransaction.Dispose()
>
> в System.Windows.Forms.Label.OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
>
> в System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Text(String value)
>
> в System.Windows.Forms.Label.set_Text(String value)
>
> в WFControlsLib2.ModBusControls.LabelReg.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Object s, EventArgs e)
>
> в D:\doc\C#\WFControlsLib2\ModBusControls\LabelReg.cs:строка 304
>
> в WFControlsLib2.ModBusControls.LabelReg.reg_OnResultRead(Reg sender, Error result, Object data)
>
> в D:\doc\C#\WFControlsLib2\ModBusControls\LabelReg.cs:строка 311
>
> в System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
>
> в System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)

Как устранить эту проблему? По идее, я просто задаю текстовое значение свойству Text классу Label.

Update...
Перегрузил и залочил метод Text

```
public override string Text
{
    get
    {
        lock (mutex)
        {
            return base.Text;
        }
    }

    set
    {
        lock (mutex)
        {
            base.Text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

mutex типа **object**, член класса, проблема осталась.

Comment: Возможно, ошибка не в том месте, в котором Вы ищете. Что такое `Units`? Желательно пример кода.

Comment: Пример сейчас не могу предоставить, но Units так же как и DisplayFormat это строковые свойства типа **string Units {get; set;}**

Comment: Если проблема еще актуальна, попробуйте следующее. Генерируйте Ваш текст не с помощью `StringBuilder`, а используя просто `String`. Или, как советовали ниже, создайте переменную `var tmp = sb.ToString();` **перед** созданием `Action d = ...`. И внутри анонимной функции используйте `tmp` а не `sb`.

Comment: Ранее в комментариях я указал, что пробовал просто константу записывать в Text, проблема остается. Т.е. проблема не в в том что записывается, а в том куда записывается.

Comment: Насколько я вижу, ошибка происходит во время обработки `Layot` (`PerformLayout`,`ResumeLayout` и т.д.). Т.е., при добавлении\изменении текста в `label`, происходит перереисовка эелемента управления. Поскольку ошибка явно говорит, что **Коллекция была изменена после создания экземпляра перечислителя**, то возможно где-то в другом потоке меняется (добавляется\удаляется) контроллеры в этом контейнере.

Comment: Проблема в том, что я работаю только в этом месте (получаю новые данные и присваиваю свойству Text). Label находится на форме и больше никаких действий не происходит. То есть все возможные действия по изменения (добавлению/удалению) происходят на системном уровне. Получается мне надо что то проверить перед присваиванием?

Comment: Что значит, "То есть все возможные действия по изменения (добавлению/удалению) происходят на системном уровне"? У вас динамически меняется количество контролов(`control`) на форме, где раположен данный `label`?

Comment: Нет, они все размещены однократно и не добавляются/не удаляются.

Comment: Ваш объект `mutex` **статический** член класса? Должен быть статическим.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, проблема все-таки в одновременном обращении к свойству `Text` объекта `label` из разных потоков.

Как советовал @Alexsandr Ter, поставьте блокировку на изменение свойства `Text`.

**Например:**

```
  Action d = () =>
  {        
    //Следующий код выполняется в однопоточном режиме.
    lock(lockObj)
    {
      this.Text = sb.ToString();

      this.Enabled = (result == ModBusCommon.Error.OK);
    }
  }
```

**Важно:**

Свойство `lockObj` должен быть статическим членом класса.

**Например**

```
class LabelReg
{
   private static Object lockObj = new Object();
   ...
}
```

Comment: Читайте комментарии, я уже пробовал лочить, проблему это не решает.

Comment: Читайте пункт **ВАЖНО** в моем ответе. Вы не правильно использовали `lock`. Конечно, если вы использовали его так, как предложил @Alexsandr Ter.

Comment: Я делал как предложил @Alexsandr Ter и делал через **Mutex**, который являлся членом класса. Проблема в том, что таким образом обеспечивается безопасность записи в **this.Text** только через данную функцию **reg_OnResultRead**. Это не обеспечивает безопасность доступа другим потоком, который может обращаться к свойству **this.Text** напрямую.

Comment: В таком случае, если имеется возможность, то может выделить присвоение свойству `Text` в отдельный метод. И этот отдельный метод сделать потокобезопасным. И, естественно, все изменения `Text` делать через этот метод.

Comment: Я то могу делать присвоения через спец метод, но система будет работать по прежнему с свойством Text напрямую. Или вы предлагаете переопределить само свойство Text ?

Comment: Извините, я не очень понял. Поясните Вашу мысль про "система будет работать по прежнему с свойством Text напрямую".

Comment: Вы предлагаете добавить новый потокобезопасный метод для работы с Text. Но допустим потребовалась перерисовка формы системой, и она будет брать значение из Text напрямую, не используя новый метод. Она ничего о нем не знает.

Comment: Думаю, ничего страшного в этом нет. Поскольку похоже ошибка в том, что когда один поток отрисовывает свойство `Text`, другой поток это свойство меняет.

Comment: И как поток, который отрисовывает свойство Text, сообщит потоку в котором изменяется свойство через безопасный метод, если первый поток о новом методе ничего не знает?

Comment: Поскольку Вы используете `invoke`, то отрисовка будет проиходить в потоке, в котором создан элемент управления. И более того, если правильно реализуете `lock`, то это изменение будет происходить в однопоточном режиме.

Comment: Что по мешает другому потоку сделать myLabel.Text = "test" ? И как потокобезопасный новый метод обеспечит безопасность?

Comment: Помешаете Вы, путем написания кода, который будет обращаться к свойству `Text` только через Ваш метод. Как вы написали Выше "Я то могу делать присвоения через спец метод, но система будет работать по прежнему с свойством Text напрямую.". В общем, Вы бы лучше попробовали сделать.

Comment: Я так и написал что надо переопределить свойство Text, а не добавлять новый метод.

Comment: Вы хотите спорить? Или решите проблему? Хотите, принимайте мое решение - не хотите, не принимайте.

Comment: Сделал перегрузку Text, см обновление вопроса. Проблема осталась.

Answer (score -2):

Видимо у вас label  в другом потоке работает. Используйте

```
 var tmp = sb.ToString();
    object obj = new object();
    lock(obj){
       if (this.InvokeRequired)
       {
            this.Invoke(new ThreadStart(
                            delegate {
                                this.Text = tmp;
                        }));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Это просто разные способы реализовать межпоточное взаимодействие, проблему это не решает.

Comment: Возможно у вас label пытаются изменить из нескольких потоков.

Comment: Если вы про одновременный доступ из разных потоков, то было бы другое исключение. > Недопустимая операция в нескольких потоках: попытка доступа к элементу управления  не из того потока, в котором он был создан. Именно для исключения этого проверяется InvokeRequired. Выделил описание исключения в вопросе.

Comment: Тогда вариант один вы вызывает sb.ToString(), когда его уже уничтожил сборщик мусора

Comment: С какой стати он его уничтожит, если он используется ? Исключение вызывает свойство Text класса Label. Если смотреть в отладчике, то sb существует, текстовое значение в sb есть.

Comment: sb как бы локальная переменная, а делегат ее вызывает уже после уничтожения, и если она не уничтожена выводит. А видна она в отладчике так как отключена оптимизация и сборщик не удаляет переменные при дебаге)))

Comment: Во первых, sb захвачена в анонимной функции, так просто сборщик ее не удалит. Во вторых, исключение появляется именно в дебаге.

Comment: в анонимной функции ссылка на объект, посмотрите как в sb реализован ToString().

Comment: sb был изначально членом класса, проблема так же проявлялась.

Comment: попробуйте использовать var tmp = sb.ToString(); или вы уже так делали? Еще можно добавить проверку существования объекта

Comment: Сделал через var tmp = sb.ToString(); Проблема осталась. Пробовал залочить через lock (obj) то же самое, проблема осталась.

Comment: Скриншот из дебага, можно увидеть что sb существует.  ![Exception](http://i76.fastpic.ru/big/2016/0304/10/b746d72221b787b530a82af5589f5c10.png)

Comment: А если просто присвоить константу this.Text = "Test";, тогда будет понятно где проблема

Comment: Попробовал задать константу, проблема осталась.

Comment: посмотрите здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28025509/changing-label-text-in-background-worker-error